# Accessing class variables from an array

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and I'm having trouble accessing some class variables.

I have this class:

```
class emptyClass 
{
  private $ladderWinsNoCoin   = 0;    
  private $ladderWinsCoin   = 0;  
  private $arenaWinsNoCoin   = 0;     
  private $arenaWinsCoin   = 0;       
  private $ladderLossesNoCoin = 0;    
  private $ladderLossesCoin = 0;  
  private $arenaLossesNoCoin = 0;     
  private $arenaLossesCoin = 0;   

  public function getProperty($property) {
        if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
              return $this->$property;
            }
          }

    public function upOne($property) {
        if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
              $this->$property=($property+1);
            }
          }

    public function setProperty($property, $value) {
        if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
          $this->$property = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

I then create 9 instances of it in an array

```
/* Create classes in an array so we can call 
them with strings from the database*/
$classes = array(  
  'Druid'  => new emptyClass, 
  'Hunter' => new emptyClass, 
  'Mage'   => new emptyClass,
  'Paladin'=> new emptyClass, 
  'Priest' => new emptyClass, 
  'Rogue'  => new emptyClass,
  'Shaman' => new emptyClass, 
  'Warlock'=> new emptyClass, 
  'Warrior'=> new emptyClass
);
```

Next I want to increment the values of the class variables to match data got from a database and this is what I've come up with

```
foreach ($games as $game){               // Go through the games array from the database 
              $gameID = current($game);      // Unused (for now)
           $heroClass = (string)next($game); 
        $villainClass = (string)next($game); // Unused (for now)
                 $win = (int)next($game);
                $coin = (int)next($game);
              $ladder = (int)next($game);

                         //Add up the values in the class objects
               if ($ladder==1&&$coin==1&&$win==1){          // Ladder win with coin
        $classes[$heroClass] -> {upOne($ladderWinsCoin)};
    } else if ($ladder==1&&$coin==1&&$win==0){  // Ladder loss with coin
        $classes[$heroClass] -> {upOne($ladderLossesCoin)}; 
    } else if ($ladder==1&&$coin==0&&$win==1){  // Ladder win without coin
        $classes[$heroClass] -> {upOne($ladderWinsNoCoin)};
    } else if ($ladder==1&&$coin==0&&$win==0){  // Ladder loss without coin
        $classes[$heroClass] -> {upOne($ladderLossesNoCoin)};
    } else if ($ladder==0&&$coin==1&&$win==1){  // Arena win with coin
        $classes[$heroClass] -> {upOne($arenaLossesCoin)};
    } else if ($ladder==0&&$coin==1&&$win==0){  // Arena loss with coin
        $classes[$heroClass] -> {upOne($arenaLossesCoin)}; 
    } else if ($ladder==0&&$coin==0&&$win==1){  // Arena win without coin
        $classes[$heroClass] -> {upOne($arenaWinsNoCoin)};
    } else if ($ladder==0&&$coin==0&&$win==0){  // Arena loss without coin
        $classes[$heroClass] -> {upOne($arenaLossesNoCoin)};
    }
```

Where `$game` is an array from the database that looks something like this

`[1, 'Mage', 'Druid', 1, 0, 1]`

When it runs I get a fatal error

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function setProperty() in /home/vooders/public_html/gameReader.php on line 48`

---

Edit:

So after trying renaming the getter/setter I'm still getting the fatal error, so now I'm sure its how I'm calling the objects.

I'll try to talk you through my thinking

`$classes[$heroClass] -> {upOne($ladderWinsCoin)};`

If we take  this line above, `$heroClass` will be a string from the database in this example `'Mage'`.

Now I want to use this string to call the right object from the `$classes` array then increment the appropriate variable by 1.

Comment: `__set` and `__get` are [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php). According to the docs - `You cannot have functions with these names in any of your classes unless you want the magic functionality associated with them.`. You explicitly calling them, could be wrong. Try renaming them to something else.

Comment: Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704038/how-to-access-multiple-properties-with-magic-method-get-set) might be useful for handling multiple properties you are dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//it should work now
<?
class emptyClass {
        private $ladderWinsNoCoin   = 5;    private $ladderWinsCoin   = 0;  private $arenaWinsNoCoin   = 0;     private $arenaWinsCoin   = 0;       
        private $ladderLossesNoCoin = 0;    private $ladderLossesCoin = 0;  private $arenaLossesNoCoin = 0;     private $arenaLossesCoin = 0;   

        public function getProperty($property) {
            if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
                  return $this->$property;
                }
              }

        public function setProperty($property, $value) {
            if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
              $this->$property = $value;
            }
        }
         public function upOne($property) {
            if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
                  $this->$property++;
            }
          }
}

$classes = array(
    'Druids'    => new emptyClass,
    'Elfos'     => new emptyClass
); 
$classes["Druids"]->setProperty("ladderWinsNoCoin",50);
echo $classes["Druids"]->getProperty("ladderWinsNoCoin") . "<br>";

$classes["Druids"]->upOne("ladderWinsNoCoin");
echo $classes["Druids"]->getProperty("ladderWinsNoCoin"). "<br>";

$classes["Elfos"]->setProperty("ladderLossesCoin",25);
echo $classes["Elfos"]->getProperty("ladderLossesCoin"). "<br>";

$classes["Elfos"]->upOne("ladderLossesCoin");
echo $classes["Elfos"]->getProperty("ladderLossesCoin"). "<br>";

//50
//51
//25
//26
?>
```

Comment: Tried renaming the functions with the same effect so I'm calling the objects wrong I think

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was what i was doing wrong i was passing the variables like `$ladderWinsCoin` rather than as strings `'ladderWinsNoCoin'` thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Categorically, I would advise you not to "write code *external to* a class that knows the class's business."

*"I am a **class.** Therefore, I am **alive.** Tell me what has happened and I shall respond accordingly.  Ask me what you want to know and I shall provide you with the answer.  **But:**  Do Not Meddle in the Affairs of Classes, for you are crunchy and taste good with worcestershire sauce!!"*

(1) Don't put your sticky fingers on the class's variables "from outside."  *Tell the Class* what has happened, that it may increment or decrement its own properties.  (You *did* say they were `private`, didn't you?  As they should be.)

(2) If you want to know "an answer," which may be based on the value of one or many properties, according to simple or complex logic, then *the Class* should contain that logic, as it pertains "to itself."

Comment: cheers for that you are right! I have made a class function to increment the value. Not sure why I didn't to start with, but I'm still having the same problem with calling the object to start with.